# What's the difference between xshift/yshift and relative coordinates while drawing an arrow between nodes?

Tags: tikz-arrows, coordinates, node-connections

Last night I crafted this piece of `LaTeX`, using relative coordinates to join nodes with arrows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %for [above], [below] and shit.
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[generic_scheme]
        \tikzstyle{block}=[draw,shape=rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm,
            minimum height=1cm]
        \tikzstyle{f_arrow}=[->, thick]
        \tikzstyle{d_arrow}=[<->, thick]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
            \node[block] (nuc) [] {Intel NUC};
            \node[block] (power) [above=of nuc, yshift=0.5cm]
                {Power\\Circuit};
            \node[block] (smps) [left=of nuc, yshift=1.25cm] {SMPS};

            \draw[f_arrow] (power.south) -- (nuc.north);
            \draw[f_arrow] (power.west)++(0, -0.25) --
                (smps.east)++(0, 0.25);
            \draw[d_arrow] (nuc.west)++(0, 0.25) --
                (smps.east)++(0, -0.25);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result was kind a puzzling:
[image: Lines using relative coordinates between nodes]

Today I've tried this alternative way using `yshift` instead of relative coordinate:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %for [above], [below] and shit.
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[generic_scheme]
        \tikzstyle{block}=[draw,shape=rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm,
            minimum height=1cm]
        \tikzstyle{f_arrow}=[->, thick]
        \tikzstyle{d_arrow}=[<->, thick]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
            \node[block] (nuc) [] {Intel NUC};
            \node[block] (power) [above=of nuc, yshift=0.5cm]
                {Power\\Circuit};
            \node[block] (smps) [left=of nuc, yshift=1.25cm] {SMPS};

            \draw[f_arrow] (power.south) -- (nuc.north);
            \draw[f_arrow] ([yshift=-0.25cm]power.west) --
                ([yshift=0.25cm]smps.east);
            \draw[d_arrow] ([yshift=0.25cm]nuc.west) --
                ([yshift=-0.25cm]smps.east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which worked as supposed to:
[image: Lines using yshift between nodes.]

So, my question would be, what's the difference between these, seemingly "identical" pieces of `LaTeX`? Am I missing something trivial while trying to understand how does `relative coordinate` and `yshift` works? Or is it just a bug in my stock `Ubuntu 14.04` pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 installation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that using

```
\draw[d_arrow] (nuc.west)++(0, 0.25) --
                (smps.east)++(0, -0.25);
```

you are *not* adding/subtracting 0.25 from the coordinates without affecting the path. You are moving the pencil, as the following simple example shows (look where the line ends in both cases and where the arrow tip results):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (6,3);
\draw (0,0)++(0.5,0.5) -- (2,2)++(0.5,0.5);
\draw[->] (3,0)++(0.5,0.5) -- (5,2)++(0.5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The sequence

```
\draw[->] (3,0)++(0.5,0.5) -- (5,2)++(0.5,0.5);
```

can be seen as:

- Move the pencil to (3,0).
- Move it (but without drawing) additionally 0.5 in both x and y coordinates.
- Start drawing to (5,2).
- Move the pencil additionally 0.5 in both coordintaes again (but there's no drawing now).
- Place the arrow tip(s).

If you want to add the values, use shifts or the `calc` library (perhaps an overkill here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (6,3);
\draw[->] ([shift={(0.5,0.5)}]0,0) -- ([shift={(0.5,0.5)}]2,2);
\draw[->] ( $ (3,0) +(0.5,0.5) $ ) -- ( $ (5,2) + (0.5,0.5) $ );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: aha! Thank You very much for clarification. So, that's why it only works on starting point of the arrow.... But why it also loses a  pointer? `[<->]` turns into `[<-]`

Comment: @Kamiccolo No, it doen't loose it; it draws it twice in the same location.